# Combine months daily files into one?

Tags: python, csv

**Problem Statement:**

Given daily csv files for every day of every month for the past 12 months on a Linux system, what is the best way to amalgamate daily files into monthly files, resulting in monthly files using python?

**File Name Examples**

alf.history.alerts.2016-02-24

alf.history.alerts.2016-04-24

*Thanks for the input in advance everyone! Hoping to learn something as a part of asking this.*

Comment: Are data in the files strictly daily, that is, midnight to midnight? If so, you could just concatenate the files using bash.

Comment: Yea, I know how to do it in BASH. Essentially look for 01* ...12* and create monthly files out of it. Wanted to understand how to do the same in Python :)

Comment: Have you coded anything so far (even in BASH)?

Comment: @telecomToperl: In Python, it's sort of the same: use `open`, `read`, `write`, order the files properly. It would still be noticeably slower using Python, I suspect.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't write any code, so I won't either.

- You can get a list of files with [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html)
- Your files, when sorted by filename, are also sorted by day (that's good)
- You can use [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) on the sorted list to group them by month. As criteria for `groupby`, you could use `filename[:-3]`. Example : `"alf.history.alerts.2016-02-24"[:-3] >>> "alf.history.alerts.2016-02"`
- You then have 12 groups of csv files. For each group, create a new csv file, iterate over sorted csvs and write their content to the monthly csv file.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks Eric. I am glad you didn't just give the answer. I'll try it out and come back if I have questions!